# How to create ItemMenu and onItemClickListener for RecyclerView?

Tags: android

How to create menu and onItemClickListener for RecyclerView? I've implemented a popup menu in each card item(Recycler View Item) and custom onItemClickListener using addOnItemTouchListener.

I'm following [this](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/) tutorial to implement onItemClickListener.
custom onItemClickListener snippet from Fragment.

```
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerClickListener(getActivity(),
            new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }));
```

menu population code from RecyclerViewAdapter,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.threeDots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(view, position);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on cardView's menu, always onItemClickListener is called. How do I achieve ItemMenu click and item click in a same recycler view?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create interface for item click.

```
public interface RecyclerClickIntegration {
    void onItemClick(View  view,int position);
}
```

**popup_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:title="One"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:title="Two"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:title="Three"/>

</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerClickIntegration, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {


    private ArrayList<String> alData;
    private PopupMenu popupMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        alData = new ArrayList<>();
        alData.add("Kintan");
        alData.add("Patel");
        alData.add("Moin");
        alData.add("Pathan");
        alData.add("Nayan");
        alData.add("Sam");
        alData.add("Jigar");
        alData.add("Sandip");

        MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(alData, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
        popupMenu.show();
    }
}
```

**Adapter for Recycler view**

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private RecyclerClickIntegration clickIntegration;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, RecyclerClickIntegration clickIntegration) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.clickIntegration = clickIntegration;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lay_stud, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(arrayList.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


    public interface RecyclerClickIntegration {
        void onItemClick(View  view,int position);
    }

    // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtViewTitle;
        public ImageView imgViewIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (clickIntegration != null) {
                        clickIntegration.onItemClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

**Template for recyclerview cell**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <!-- icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <!-- title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
        android:text="Kintan Patel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Final Result]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class that implements OnClickListener

   ```
   public class RecyclerViewItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
   private int position;
   private View view;

   public RecyclerViewItemClickListener(View view,int position) {
       this.position = position;
       this.view = view;
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.item_one:
               break;
           case R.id.root:
               break;
       }
   }}
   ```
2. Set this custom OnClickListener to each item's root view & other items

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) { 
    holder.threeDots.setOnClickListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener(holder.threeDots,position));
    holder.threeDots.setOnClickListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener(holder.base,position)); 
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener,View.OnClickListener{
    private String displayName;
    public final TextView nameText;
    public MyViewViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        nameText= ...
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        nameText.setText(name);
        displayName=name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Tag","click:"+displayName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(0, R.id.menuitemid, 0, "Delete").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Log.d("Tag","Delete:"+displayName);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```